# Python dictReader() for CSV files in C#

Tags: c#, python, parsing

I need to parse a CSV file in C# in the same way Python dictRead() does.
This is my Python code:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

And I need to do the same thing in C#
I already tried `parser.ReadFields()` but it doesn't work the way I want.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToCsv

Comment: http://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: _it doesn't work the way I want._:  In what way does it not work the way you want?

Comment: It means it gives me some problem when parsing field with double quotes(") in it.

Comment: You'll want to use one of the third party libraries @LismUK or myself mentioned above. If you have the option, pipe delimited is best. If you must, I found a good `Regex` that works pretty well, `,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)`. If you're dealing with a lot of fields/rows you'll want to make sure it's a `Compiled` regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments to your question, a third party library like [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/) or [LinqToCSV](http://nuget.org/packages/LinqToCsv) will perform the necessary actions of splitting and writing `.csv` files.

In addition, I found a regex here on SO that works well and I've used it with no issue in several applications.

Here is a snippet where I use it as a string extension:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class StrExtensions
{
    private static Regex csvSplit = 
        new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", RegexOptions.Compiled);


    public static string[] FieldsFromCSV(this string str)
    {
        return csvSplit.Split(str);
    }
}
```

Then, you can just say:

```
string[] fields = line.FieldsFromCSV();
```